# Classes / methods - removed / changed in SDK

Tags: java

I was having the discussion today whether any classes or methods have ever been removed from the core Java SDK over the years. I know stuff gets deprecated but has it ever been changed or removed?

I thought it had (I can't think of examples) so maybe I am wrong.

I read some articles online which suggested that nothing had been removed - ever!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Backward compatibility is very important with Java, so if there are any examples, they will be very few.

Comment: Yeah I felt there would be few but I was sure that there must be some!

Answer (score 3):

Best you have a look at this article by Oracle: [Java SE 7 and JDK 7 Compatibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html)

A small copy paste from the article:

**Source Compatibility**

Java SE 7 includes new language features and platform APIs. If these are used in a source file, that source file cannot be compiled on an earlier version of the Java platform.

In general, the source compatibility policy is to avoid introducing source code incompatibilities.

Deprecated APIs are interfaces that are supported only for compatibility with previous releases. The javac compiler generates a warning message whenever one of these is used, unless the -nowarn command-line option is used. It is recommended that programs be modified to eliminate the use of deprecated APIs, **although there are no current plans to remove such APIs entirely from the system.**

Some APIs in the sun.* packages have changed. These APIs are not intended for use by developers. Developers importing from sun.* packages do so at their own risk. For more details, see [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call sun.* Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).

Comment: Thanks for response. It's states that there are "no current plans". But what I am asking is has it ever been done deliberately (or accidentally - unlikely) in any of the previous versions. It's been 17 years!

Comment: None that i know of, but i am only doing JAVA for 12 years, so i did miss the first few...

Comment: Thanks - It sounds like I am wrong on this. But i feel something broke on me in the past! Maybe it was in the core SDK.

Comment: Oops. WASN'T in the core SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There are compatibility docs on doc.oracle.com which [include sections on incompatibilities](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html#incompatibilities). You can find little nuggets in those docs like...

> > - The apt functionality has been superceded by standardized annotation processing in JSR 269. Running the apt tool in JDK 7 prints a warning that it will be removed in the next major release.
> > - JVMDI was removed and JVMPI was disabled in Java SE 6
> > - The XSLTProcessorApplet Class is Removed